# How to access the UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, thread-safety, threadpool

I have a Winform APP that does a simple task.
There is an event listener for a button that create a new thread:

```
  ThreadStart work = (addToList);
  Thread thread = new Thread(work);
  thread.Start();
```

Now I need the second part of the calculation ot be done with the UI thread (so my instruction ask)
"
Note that you need to access the list box within the UI thread (hint: you can use Control.Invoke for WinForm
"

Any idea how to do so?

Comment: The instructor already told you; have you looked on MSDN for the documentation and examples for `Control.Invoke`? Because *that's what you do*; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke

Comment: Look I know that, I did read about it but I am a beginner and I do not fully understand it.

Comment: Did you see the example in the documentation? What exactly is unclear to you?

Answer (score 3):

The `Invoke` method needs a delegate (reference to a function) and will schedule that on UI thread. Considering that all the elements on the form share the same thread as UI thread, you can use the `Invoke` method from either the form or any of its controls:

```cs
class MyForm
{
  private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FullCalculation));
    thread.Start();
  }
  
  private void FullCalculation()
  {
    OffUIThreadCalculation();
    this.Invoke(OnUIThreadCalculation); // Schedules OnUIThreadCalculation to run on the UI thread of `this`, aka the form
  }

  private void OffUIThreadCalculation()
  {
    // UI elements should not be used here
  }

  private void OnUIThreadCalculation()
  {
    // UI elements can be used here
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Reza, but with this method the same Thread is working on both methods..

Comment: `OffUIThreadCalculation` and `OnUIThreadCalculation` run on different threads. `OffUIThreadCalculation` runs on the thread that is created through `thread.Start`, but `OnUIThreadCalculation` runs on the UI thread from which you created the worker thread.